# Dead code and/or how to generate a cross reference from Haskell source

Tags: haskell, ghc, dead-code, code-elimination

I've got some unused functionality in my codebase, but it's hard to identify. The code has evolved over the last year as I explore its problem space and possible solutions. What I'm *needing* to do is find that unused code so I can get rid of it. I'm happy if it deals with the problem on an exportable name basis.GHC has warnings that deal with non-exported unused code. Any tools specific to this task would be of interest.

However, I'm curious about a comprehensive cross referencing tool. I can find the unused code with such a tool. Years ago when I was working in C and assembler, I found that a good xref was a pretty handy tool, useful for many different purposes.

I'm getting nowhere with googling. Apparently in Haskell the dominant meaning of cross-reference is within literate programming. Though maybe something there would be useful.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don’t know of such a tool, so in the past I have done a bit of a hack instead.

If you have a comprehensive test suite, you can run it with GHC’s [code coverage](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/hpc.html) tracing enabled. Compile with `-fhpc` and use `hpc markup` to generate annotated source. This gives you the union of *unused* code and *untested* code, both of which you would probably like to address anyway.

[SourceGraph](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SourceGraph) can give you [a bunch of information](http://code.haskell.org/~ivanm/Sample_SourceGraph/SampleReports.html) which you may also find useful.

Comment: Thanks. I had considered about the code coverage route but thought I'd see if there was a better way. Maybe that's the quickest route to what I need. SourceGraph is something I'd not heard of. I tried to install it but have a bunch of version incompatibilities. Sigh. I'll try to resolve these on Monday or Tuesday (unless the code coverage works well).

Comment: I could not get Graphalyze to compile, and SourceGraph depends on it. Too bad because it looks as though there's a lot of useful information provided. I had a look at the code coverage tool and I will be able to answer my immediate question from it's output. So, my question is answered. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is now a tool for this very purpose: https://hackage.haskell.org/package/weeder

It's been around since 2017, and while it has limitations, it definitely helps with large codebases.