# Finding unused Haskell functions in a module or file?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is there a way to automatically find unused functions (and constants) in a module or `.hs` file? Specifically, I mean those functions that are not used (directly or indirectly) by the functions in the export list of the current module/file.

I know that e.g. Emacs haskell mode has the ability to warn about unused `import`S as follows:
`The import of XXX is redundant`

Is there similar tool or method for finding *unused functions*?

Note: I know this can be done manually by deleting some code and see whether it still compiles. But it's tedious process.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25649143/how-to-enable-dead-code-warnings-in-haskell-ghc?rq=1 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409508/dead-code-and-or-how-to-generate-a-cross-reference-from-haskell-source?rq=1

Comment: Another related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18409508/dead-code-and-or-how-to-generate-a-cross-reference-from-haskell-source

Comment: You might want to try [ghc-mod](https://github.com/DanielG/ghc-mod/wiki/Frontend)

Answer (score 7):

Here are some relevant ghc `-W` flags:

```
-Wunused-binds
-Wunused-do-bind
-Wunused-foralls
-Wunused-imports
-Wunused-local-binds
-Wunused-matches
-Wunused-pattern-binds
-Wunused-top-binds
-Wunused-type-patterns
```

Or just use `-Wall`. You can get a complete list of ghc flags with `ghc --show-options`.